# Best way to get a python game to continue to run

Tags: python

Beginner project review.

I made  a simple guess the random number game and set it up so it should run continuously until you say you don't want to play again. I used some code I found online for the base of the game. So i was wondering if you guys could look at the end of the code and tell me if i did this the best way possible. I've tested it a bunch and it does. Just wondering if im doing it the most efficient way.

```
def playAgainfunc():
    print("You won't play again. To play again press 'Y'. To exit press anything else.")
    playAgainresponse = input()

    if playAgainresponse == 'Y':
        baseGamefunction()
        playAgainfunc()
    if playAgainresponse == 'y':
        baseGamefunction()
        playAgainfunc()
    else:
        print("Ok, I didn't want to play again anyway")

baseGamefunction()
playAgainfunc()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use an infinite loop.

Comment: post your answer at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: also fix your code indentation, it is crucial in **Python** world

Answer (score 1):

```
def baseGamefunction():
    ....

while True:
   baseGamefunction()
   if input("Do you want to play again? (y/N) ").lower() not in ["y", "yes"]:
       break
```

Use a `while` loop and quit if the user inputs anything other than `y` or `yes`.

If using `python2`, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no experience with Python myself, I do have a little bit with Java. I think it would be more efficient to use a while loop instead, if you have learned them. As a general rule of thumb, if you are repeating code, you will be losing a bit of efficiency.

```
while playAgain.lower() == 'y':
    baseGamefunction()
    playAgainfunc()
else:
    print("Ok, I didn't want to play again anyway")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not efficient in terms of code volume as you do a separate tests for the upper and lower case `Y`. Instead convert the input to lower (or upper) case and test against that case.

See the below code, which defines your functionality in less code, with no repetition.

```
def baseGameFunction():
    print('placeholder for actual game.')

while True:

    baseGameFunction()

    resp = input('play again? ')

    if resp.lower() != 'y':
        break

print('thanks for playing')
```